# Limiting mobile apps accessing server API

Tags: asp.net, mobile

When we build website access our API on a application server via HTTP request. We can limit the domain name od the client calling the API to access. Now, if we build mobile apps, how do we identify the app is authorised? We cannot get any user agent. Any method to check this?

On server, we build using ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

> We can limit the domain name of the client calling the API to access.

Checking the caller's IP/domain can be one factor in authentication/authorization, but in my opinion it shouldn't be the **only** factor. Such evidence can be forged, and it's also not granular: you don't know exactly who the user is, just where they (might have) come from.

> Now, if we build mobile apps, how do we identify the app is
>   authorised?

Use a proper authentication/authorization mechanism that's suited to the business need. If the application pertains to a particular user's data, require a username and password to be passed to your API over SSL. Better yet, become familiar with [OpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/).

Comment: OAuth is a good way for authentication of user. I am going to develop an app that do not want someone to write another client/app to use our server API. Does OAuth can limit this?

Comment: If you don't do it on a user by user basis, then you are limited in being able to "turn off" a single device or assign specific permissions to a user. If that doesn't matter at all (usually it **does** matter), then you can use a single set of login credentials (OAuth would probably work, but really doesn't provide much value for a single login).